# Lockless Queue and Pointer woes

Tags: c, windows, synchronization

I have been asked to implement a lock free queue in c using compare and exchange, however my knowledge of pointers is fairly limited.

I have been using the following code to test my (as yet incomplete) dequeue implementation, but I believe it is looping infinitely because I'm not terribly sure how to properly use pointers/address of operator.

I have been given this CAS function to use, since I know nothing of assembler.

```
long __cdecl compare_exchange(long *flag, long oldvalue, long newvalue)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, flag
        mov eax, oldvalue
        mov ebx, newvalue
        lock cmpxchg [ecx], ebx
        jz iftrue
    }
    return 0;
    iftrue: return 1;
}
```

My current (relevant) code is as follows...

```
typedef struct QueueItem
{
    int data;
    struct QueueItem* next;
}item;

struct Queue
{
    item *head;
    item *tail;
}*queue;

int Dequeue()
{
    item *head;

    do
    {
        head = queue->head;
        if(head == NULL)
            return NULL_ITEM;
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", (long *)queue->head, (long)&head, (long)&head->next);
    }
    while(!compare_exchange((long *)queue->head, (long)&head, (long)&head->next)); // Infinite loop.

    return head->data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    item i, j;

    queue = (struct Queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));

    // Manually enqueue some data for testing dequeue.
    i.data = 5;
    j.data = 10;
    i.next = &j;
    j.next = NULL;

    queue->head = &i;

    printf("Dequeued: %d\n", Dequeue());
    printf("Dequeued: %d\n", Dequeue());
}
```

Should I be using the not operator inside of the do while loop? If I don't use that operator, I get an output of "Dequeued 5" x2, which suggests the swap isn't happening and that I should use the not. If so, where am I going wrong? I'd put money on it being a pointer/address operator issue.

Comment: How much money are we talking about? ;)

Comment: But seriously, why is there a while loop for dequeuing something? Shouldn't you be dequeuing from head? Are you trying to _wait_ for an item to come in? Does the infinite loop happen with the first call to `Dequeue` or the second?

Comment: @Shahbaz That's a fairly standard CAS loop. If 2+ threads are trying to modify the same word at the same time, only a single CAS instruction will succeed and all others will fail. In the case of failure you read the word again and retry the operation until the CAS succeed. Here's some [Reading material](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) :)

Comment: @Revelation I strongly recommend that you don't try to implement lock-free algorithms if you don't have a good command of your language of choice. To put it bluntly, if you don't understand how to properly handle pointers, you're heading for a world of pain and misery. Just make your life easier and use a simple lock. Also the Win32 API provides a perfectly good family of lock-free functions (`InterlockedXxx`) including a CAS function. There's no real reason to make up your own here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is confusion on the pointers and values. Here is corrected code:

```
 do
 {
    head = queue->head;
    if(head == NULL)
        return 0;
    printf("%d, %d, %d %d\n", (long *)queue->head, (long)head, (long)head->next, head->data);
  }  while (!compare_exchange((long *)&queue->head,   (long)head, (long)head->next));
```

You were trying to write what queue->head was pointing to, not the value of queue->head itself.

In addition, to make it work properly on multicore, I believe you need to define the head as volatile.

```
struct Queue
{
   volatile item *head;
   item *tail;
}*queue;
```

Comment: The volatile keyword here is not necessary because `cmpxchg` is a memory fence which should force a sync of the writes at the CPU level. At the compiler level (for gcc anyway), the assembly block should disable instruction reordering across its boundaries. This means that the volatile keyword would only disable useful optimizations that wouldn't affect the correctness of the program.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did some reading in the interim and realised that this was likely the case, but before I could try it out I noticed that this response confirmed it.

Comment: It's more complicated than this because the code as written leaks dequeued nodes. (But gets away with it since the nodes are allocated on the caller's stack, which is not particularly realistic.) If you fix the memory leak, then you have the problem that two racing threads may both try to dequeue, and one of them may free the node while the other is trying to access its `head->next`, resulting in undefined behavior (accessing freed memory). Since you say this is Windows, then in real life you should just use the `InterlockedPopEntrySList` function.